# In PhpStorm How do you untab to the previous tabstop?

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm, when dealing with soft/smart-tabs can I jump back to the previous tabstop with one key press or combo?

I tried Shift+Tab but it doesn't jump back to the tabstop, it jumps back by the size of the softtab.

Here is an illustration where a soft tab is 4 spaces:

```
Notabs (0 spaces)
••••Tabstop1 (1 Tab)
••••••••Tabstop2 (2 Tabs)
••••••* My cursors is here in between Tabstop 1 + 2
••••••••<- another Tab press moves me to Level2
••••<- I want to get here, back to Level1 (in one key press)
••<- Shift+Tab moves me here (back 4 full spaces, a full soft tab)
```

In retrospect I can live with just backspacing a 3 to 1 times, and use Shift+Tab when traversing a tabstop or more of distance, but I'm just curious if there is a direct analogy to the way the Tab key works for un-tabbing stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe you can clarify with an image or commented code example?

Comment: Good point, illustration added.

Comment: It could be a bug depending on the file type and your code style settings, it's recommended to report it at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA with all the details required to reproduce.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a little combo: press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

It is not in one key press, but it is regardless of number of spaces (1 or 2 or 3) you want to jump over. No need to calculate how many backspaces you need: every time press 2 times.

Comment: Very logical. Not my ideal but simpler than what I was doing.

Comment: Can I configure backspace to behave like shift+tab does? I've been using aptana studio, and even though it was a bit buggy, this feature was working like a charm (backspace jumped back a whole tab, not just one space).

Comment: @A.Sallai in PhpStorm 10 (and maybe previous but I didn't use prev versions) you can under Settings>Editor>General>SmartKeys>Backspace>Unindent: "To nearest indent position"